# How to backup database with the data from .frm file

Tags: mysql

My project was deployed in ubantu 9.0. For some reasons ubantu was crash. I can't access mysql.

I copied whole data from "mysql..../data" to another pc "mysql..../data" ,
Its show the database but didn't get the data.

If I select the tables its show me error like "table don't exists...";

Anyone can tell me what i have to do to get the data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

backing up your data is not as simple as copying a directory.
you should dump your db, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html
if you can't run mysql anymore, try the following:

- Stop your mysql server
- Create the directories that will be new datadir
- chown the directory to the mysql:mysql user
- copy the files from the old datadir to the new location. However, make sure that the files named ib_arch_log_0000000000, ib_logfile0 etc. are not copied to the newer location.
- Make sure that the files and directories are owned by mysql user
- Make changes in the my.cnf to point the new datadir.
- Restart the MySQL database